# SQL one field count on aggregate of other field

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to count a total of unit, regardless of any criteria, but also flag people that completed 3+ units of work in a on a given date.

Here's an example table and pseudo code:

```
DATE|PERSON|JOB_NO
1/1/2020 | M | 01
1/1/2020 | M | 02
1/1/2020 | N | 03
1/1/2020 | M | 04
```

pseudo code:

```
SELECT DATE, COUNT(ALL UNITS), COUNT(DISTINCT PERSON WHERE PERSON DID MORE THAN 3+ UNITS)
FROM DB
GROUP BY DATE
```

So from the table M did 3 jobs so they count but N did 1 job so they don't I'd get:

```
1/1/2020 | 4 | 1
```

Comment: Please attempt to solve the problem first and then we can better assist you in your understanding of how to accomplish this goal. Once you have an attempt that is not working or not giving you the correct results, please update the question with the query that you have written. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function to get the persons that completed 3+ units and then aggregate:

```
SELECT t.[DATE], COUNT(*) [ALL UNITS],
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t.counter >=3 THEN [PERSON] END) [DISTINCT PERSON]
FROM (  
  SELECT *, COUNT([JOB_NO]) OVER (PARTITION BY [DATE], [PERSON]) counter
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY t.[DATE]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ea9339e1b6521e81792525b8b8662e2).
Results:

```
> DATE                | ALL UNITS | DISTINCT PERSON
> :------------------ | --------: | --------------:
> 01/01/2020 00:00:00 |         4 |               1
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been beating my head against subqueries all day, but the partition was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think someone already answered this correctly but here ya go

```
drop  table #tmp

create table #tmp
    (
        [date] date
        , person char(1)
        , jobno int
    );

insert into #tmp
( date, person, jobno )
values ('1/1/2020', 'm',1), ('1/1/2020', 'm',2), ('1/1/2020', 'n',1), ('1/1/2020', 'm',3)

SELECT
    DATE,
    COUNT(*),
    (SELECT COUNT(distinct person) FROM #tmp GROUP BY person, date HAVING COUNT(*)>=3)
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation to compute the daily count of persons that have performed 3+ jobs:

```
select date, count(*) cnt
from (select date, person from mytable group by date, person having count(*) >= 3) t
group by date
```

The inner query selects the `(date, person)` tuples that have more than 3 records in the table. The outer query counts the number of such records per day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example for count in sql if you need to view where count is 3+

```
SELECT d.nume,
FROM angajat a JOIN departament d ON a.departament_id = d.id_dep
GROUP BY d.nume
HAVING COUNT (d.nume) <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select date, sum(cnt) as total_units,
       sum(case when cnt >= 3 then 1 else 0 end) as persons_with_3
from (select date, person, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by date, person
     ) dp
group by date
order by date;
```